# How to pass the User entity results from action class to view.jsp

Tags: jstl, liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have created a portlet where I am fetching the user details filtering the list based on some condition in my action class. Now how can I pass the results (List of users) from my action class to view.jsp?

my Action class code,

```
public void addEntry(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortalException, SystemException
{
int usersCount = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount();
            List<User> usersList = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0 , usersCount);
            System.out.println("List Size is ===>"+ usersList);
            if (usersList != null) {
            for (User user : usersList) {  
                            if(user.getFacebookId() == 12345 && user.getStatus() == 0)
                            {
                                    System.out.println(((Long) user.getUserId()).toString()+ "," + user.getFullName()+ "," + user.getFirstName()+ "," + user.getLastName()+ "," + user.getScreenName());

                            }
                }
            }

}
```

In my action class I am filtering the list based on FacebookID and user status. It is printing the required users list. Now How can I send the list of filtered users to my view page.

View page code,

```
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-results
                results="<%=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd())%>"
       total="<%=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount()%>" />


        <liferay-ui:search-container-row
                className="com.liferay.portal.model.User"
                keyProperty="userId"
                modelVar="user"
        >
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="name"
                        value="<%= user.getFullName() %>"
                />

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="first-name"
                        property="firstName"
                />
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="last-name"
                        property="lastName"
                />
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="screen-name"
                        property="screenName"
                />
        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

        <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>

<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found" />
```

Any suggestions that How can I pass the filter list in action class to `liferay-ui:search-container-results`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    List<User> tempList = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (User user : usersList) {  
                                if(user.getFacebookId() == 12345 && user.getStatus() == 0)
                                {
                                  tempList.add(user);                                        
                                  System.out.println(((Long) user.getUserId()).toString()+ "," + user.getFullName()+ "," + user.getFirstName()+ "," + user.getLastName()+ "," + user.getScreenName());

                                }
     }
      actionRequest.setAttribute("userList",tempList);
```

Put up the usersList in the request object from  the Action Class by using actionRequest.setAttribute("userList",tempList); And also the user count in the same fashion. Now in the jsp just replace the following lines.

```
results="<%=request.getAttribute("userList")%>"
   total="<%=request.getAttribute("count")%>
```

Not sure you may need some type casting also on the above lines.

Comment: If I set actionRequest.setAttribute("userList",usersList);  then I will get all the users list right But I need to add the users which are printing in the "if(user.getFacebookId() == 12345 && user.getStatus() == 0)
                            { ..... }" loop. So how can I add the list of users which are coming in the If loop results. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a final query, In my action class Is there any way init method so that before render my first page, I need to add the users list to my action request. So each time while rendering my view.jsp this init method should call and set the users list in my init method . How can I do that?